# System Monitor disagrees with 'free -m'

Tags: 12.04, ram, system-monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System monitor (panel) shows the wrong amount of used ram](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46033/system-monitor-panel-shows-the-wrong-amount-of-used-ram)

When I start up my computer, `free -m` says I have about 1800MB allocated and 150MB free.  In System Monitor, it says I have about 300MB used and 1700MB free.  Which one is correct?  I am having problems getting my Java app to work and I keep getting out of memory exceptions even when System Monitor says I have 1GB+ free.  What gives?

Comment: apparently the reason is because "free -m" also lists "-/+ buffers/cache:" which is essentially free ram.  even though it is listed in a separate category